# Localizable.strings causing plist parsing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsstring, plist

I have just localized the file Localizable.strings in my Xcode project in order to localise my application to a few different languages. However, having edited each of the files in the standard "key = value" format, I receive the following parsing error, which does not specify a file making it hard to track down what it is referring to.

> CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 10. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.

I have looked through each of the *.strings files, specifically on line 10, and I found nothing of any interest or regards as to what is causing the issue. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong.

Here is a sample of a Localizable.strings file in my project. All other files follow the same format.

```
"Enter URL" = "Voer adres in"
"Headers" = "Koppen"
"Key" = "sleutel"
"Value" = "waarde"
"Parameters" = "Parameters"
"Tap to add a new line" = "Tik om een nieuwe lijn toe te voegen"
"Perform request" = "Verzoek Uitvoeren"
"Response" = "Antwoord"
"Received Headers" = "Ontvangen Koppen"
"Error" = "Fout"
"Loading" = "Verzoek aan het versturen"
```

I then use `NSLocalizedString()` to provide the translated string.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As stated in the error message, you're missing semicolons at the end of each line.

```
"foo" = "bar";
```

Is the correct format

Comment: + Make sure all quotation marks are escaped, "foo" = "\"quotation\" bar"; ("plutil" exited with code 1)

Answer (score 3):

```
"Enter URL" = "Voer adres in";
"Headers" = "Koppen";
"Key" = "sleutel";
"Value" = "waarde";
"Parameters" = "Parameters";
"Tap to add a new line" = "Tik om een nieuwe lijn toe te voegen";
"Perform request" = "Verzoek Uitvoeren";
"Response" = "Antwoord";
"Received Headers" = "Ontvangen Koppen";
"Error" = "Fout";
"Loading" = "Verzoek aan het versturen";
```

this is the correct formula

Answer (score 1):

This message can also be come due to use of :(colon) instead of ;(semicolon) at line end. Please be sure there is semicolon(;) at each end of line and also there is no colon(:) also.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4

make sure the one for all Apps file for Localizable.strings don't make more than one page just one

#### local.string  English "hi" = "hi";

#### local.string  Arabic  "hi" = "هاي";

### using

and put this extension in your app

```
extension String {
    var localizedLized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by a missing quotation mark.

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = myTestApp";
```