# Parser error While building ionic app in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I am working on a hybrid app. Here is my environment details,

- Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.2
- ios-sim version: 4.1.1
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Node Version: v0.12.7
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.3
- Build version 7D175

I am getting the following error, when I am trying to execute "ionic build ios"

```
2016-09-07 16:35:40.328 xcodebuild[10169:148374] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 48. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.

2016-09-07 16:35:40.329 xcodebuild[10169:148374] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 48. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.

2016-09-07 16:35:40.395 xcodebuild[10169:148374] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character / at line 1" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character / at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Missing ';' on line 48" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Missing ';' on line 48}}
```

I have seen related solutions like [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-app-name-in-config-xml-with-spaces/30166) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647987/localizable-strings-causing-plist-parsing-error) But these solutions are not working for me. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to remove remove\add platform? Sometimes it helps. ionic platform remove ios, ionic platform add ios, ionic build ios

Comment: Yes @Madman I have tried that also but its of no help. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: did you found any solution of your issue?

Comment: I upgraded Cordova CLI to 5.4.1 and remove\add platform and it worked for me. @Priyanka

Comment: Probably because there's a space in the App Name or the profile name

Comment: I already checked that. Thanks for your suggestion @Danny